# How can I create a self-consistent .jar file with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I wrote my Java application in Eclipse. Now I would like to generate a .jar file which can be run on other systems from the command line. Is there a easy way to do it in Eclipse?

In particular I am wondering what should I do with the jar files of external library that I use (should it be included into my .jar file?).

Moreover, should I generate some manifest files?

**ADDED:**

I see the window in which I can choose "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" or "Package required libraries into generated JAR" and so on. I select the first option, I specify export destination but "Next" button is not activated yet. What else should I specify. I am offered to launch a configuration but i do not want to. Every configuration is associated with a fixed set of parameters given in the command line and I do not want that.

Comment: Probably too late but for your second comment: the next button is always disabled in this dialogue window. The launch configuration determines which `main` method will be run when the jar is executed, so you will definitely need it for an executable jar. If you choose a launch configuration and an export destination, you should be able to select finish.

Answer (score 12):

Select you project, then `Export` => `Java` => `Runnable JAR file`

You can then choose to extract/package/copy required libraries into your JAR and also select the class, whose `main()` method should be executed on startup.

Then you can execute the generated jar via:
`java -jar yourjar.jar`

Comment: I stack on "extract/package". What it the meaning of these options? Should I "extract" or "package" libraries?

Comment: Package: External jars will remain as jar in the root of your archive.


Extract: External jars will be extracted and the class files put/mixed together with your class files.

Comment: @b_erb, so which do you prefer?

Answer (score 3):

When you go to `Export => Java => Runnable JAR file`,
You said "Next" button is not activated yet, You don't have to press the next button because you can just press finish, If you don't want the Lauch Configuration, You can manually edit the manifest file later. If you have external libraries you can chose one of the options they give you, extract/package/copy required libraries into jar file