# How can i create the exectable jar file of the complete project which contains many packages,java files, images, external libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a self-consistent .jar file with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728283/how-can-i-create-a-self-consistent-jar-file-with-eclipse)

i am involved for a java project which contains many packages, many java files and many external libraries and many images. Now How can i create a complete executable jar file ,So that i can run the application by using the jar file in any system? Please give the complete solution with example?

Comment: I have developed the application in Eclipse IDE.Please help me on this

Comment: Very specific request... Complete solution with example... Try reading about Maven and the Shader plugin for it (google it).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) eclipse plugin. This allows you to create an exe and very easily integrate what you want inside that exe.

see http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EclipseNSIS_-_NSIS_plugin_for_Eclipse