# How to export jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to export jar file with existing jar file in the project by eclipse. I exported jar file but it did not contain existing jar file in the project. How to export jar file with existing jar in the project?

I exported jar file by the following steps. 
Where is the "Package required libraries into generated JAR" checkbox? I can't see it.
Please show me how to do.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a self-consistent .jar file with Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728283/how-can-i-create-a-self-consistent-jar-file-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found was using FatJar Plug-in here: http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Eclipse 3.7.2.
Make sure you select the jar file in the select resources to export tree control (on the JAR export window).

If you want to export as Runnable JAR make sure to tick the "Package required libraries into generated JAR" checkbox." This will add the required libraries as JARs in your exported JAR.

Comment: It seems you used: File->Export->JAR file.
You need to use: File->Export->Runnable JAR file to get the "Package required libraries into generated JAR" option. You will need a launch configuration which uses MainFrame1 to be able to export this way.

Comment: I didn't find File->Export->Runnable JAR file. Why?

Comment: It seems i missed one step: File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR file. But if it's still not there, i guess you might be missing an Eclipse feature. I have this present on Eclipse Classic 3.7 (both on Windows and Linux). And i know it was there in 3.6 too. It seems to me like you have the Java EE version of Eclipse. Try installing Eclipse Java Development tools, if it's not already installed.